# How to create an upgrade-only MSI file using the WiX toolset?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) project that creates a product installer for Windows (`.msi` package). Now I have a scenario where I need to create an update package (on Windows) that only works if the product is installed on the client machine, but in any other case it simply exits.

Most likely I need the Upgrade feature (`<Upgrade ... />`) in WiX, but how do I do that?

Comment: Start with [this chapter](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization) in the tutorial. It has a sample very close to what you need to implement